# how to include grep in a regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl, grep

so i'm currently stuck on this problem:
1. i declare a constant list, say LIST
2. i want to read through a file, which i do so line by line in a while loop, and if the line has a keyword from LIST, i print the line, or so something with it.

this is what i have currently:

```
use constant LIST => ('keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3');
sub main{
    unless(open(MYFILE, $file_read)){die "Error\n"};
    while(<MYFILE>){
        my $line = $_;
        chomp($line);
        if($line =~ m//){#here is where i'm stuck, i want is if $line has either of the keywords
            print $line;
        }
    }
}
```

What should i do in that if statement to match what i want the program to do? and can i do so without having the `$line` variable and simply using `$_`? i only used $line because i thought grep would automatically place the constants in LIST into `$_`.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to define a *quoted regular expression* as your constant instead of a list:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;    # Will kill program on bad opens, closes, and writes
use feature qw(say);   # Better than "print" in most situations

use constant {
   LIST => qr/keyword1|keyword2|keyword3/, # Now a regular expression.
   FILE_READ => 'file.txt', # You're defining constants, make this one too.
};

open my $read_fh, "<", FILE_READ;  # Use scalars for file handles

# This isn't Java. You don't have to define "main" subroutine

while ( my $line = <$read_fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    if ( $line =~ LIST ) {  #Now I can use the constant as a regex
        say $line;
    }
}
close $read_fh;
```

By the way, if you don't use *autodie*, the standard way of opening a file and failing if it doesn't open is to use the `or` syntax:

```
open my $fh, "<", $file_name or die qq(Can't open file "$file_name": $!);
```

If you have to use a list as a constant, then you can use `join` to make the regular expression:

```
use constant LIST => qw( keyword1 keyword2 keyword3 );

...

my $regex = join "|", map LIST;
while ( my $line = <$file_fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    if ( $line =~ /$regex/ ) {
        say $line;
    }
}
```

The `join` takes a list (in this case, a constant list), and separates each member by the string or character you give it. I hope your keywords contain no special regular expression characters. Otherwise, you need to *quote* those special characters.

---

### Addendum

> my $regex = join '|' => map +quotemeta, LIST; – Zaid

Thanks Zaid. I didn't know about the `quotemeta` command before. I had been trying various things with `\Q` and `\E`, but it started getting too complex.

Another way to do what Zaid did:

```
my @list = map { quotemeta } LIST;
my $regex = join "|", @list;
```

The [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) is a bit difficult for beginners to understand. `map` takes each element in `LIST` and runs the [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta) command against it. This returns *list* which I assign to `@list`.

Imagine:

```
use constant LIST => qw( periods.are special.characters in.regular.expressions );
```

When I run:

```
my @list = map { quotemeta } LIST;
```

This returns the list:

```
my @list = ( "periods\.are", "special\.characters", "in\.regular\.expressions" );
```

Now, the periods are literal periods instead of special characters in the regular expression. When I run:

```
my $regex = join "|", @list;
```

I get:

```
$regex = "periods\.are|special\.characters|in\.regular\.expressions";
```

And that's a valid regular expression.

Comment: @Zaid I didn't know about the `quotemeta` command before. That works great.